# Reduce file move size

Tags: tortoise-hg, hg

So, recently, I have rearranged the files in my company's main code repo so it is more sorted and such. This involved moving almost every file to a different location in the repository and that was the only change that was made. This resulted in the `.hg` folder growing from 16 gb to 21 gb (+ 5 gb) with just one revision.

Why does this happen and is there a way I can avoid it and make that revision less large? Yes, I did use the move command and yes, I have searched Google and I haven't gotten any results to explain this or provide a way to reduce the size of the repo beyond splitting it into multiple ones (which would still likely be the same size).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the hg architecture correctly —

Mercurial's history storage format uses a single "revlog" per file; each new version is appended to the same log file. (For example, all versions of "hello.c" are kept in ".hg/store/data/hello.c.i".) Nearby revisions in the same revlog are delta-compressed to save space (sharing data between revisions of the same file).

However, the format [still does not](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=883) have any mechanism to share identical data between revlogs belonging to *different* files. As a result, if you previously had some data in file A and now have it in file B, then it has to be stored at least once in full in *each* file's revlog. You can see some progress regarding this in the Bugzilla thread [#883](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=883).

Note that `hg move` does not rewrite history. Even after you rename file A to file B, all previous revisions will still refer to it as file A, so the repository must continue to have revlogs for both files A *and* B (one containing the old revisions, the other containing new ones).